Pumping lemma for context free language ex: 0^i10^j10^k with i = max(j,k)
I quite understand the concept of pumping lemma for context-free language.
K = 0^i10^j0^k with i=max(j,k)
I do not know how to divide the words so that the condition of |vxy|<= p is respected.
I tried by suggesting that v and y contain only an 'a' at the beginning of the string so that by multiplying the number of 'a', i times the condition of the max will not be respected.
I want to know if I'm on the right way.
Thank you in advance
